# Pass input variable into jquery load function

Tags: jquery

I have an input field and I want that variable to be passed as part of the url paramter in a load request.  So for example what I am trying is

```
var inputField= $j('#inputText').val();
$j(document).ready(function() {     
    $j(".button").click(function (){    
        $j('#result').load('http://site.com?parameter='+inputField'.aClass')
    });
});
```

If I were trying to do this without the variable like

```
$j('#result').load('http://site.com?parameter=stuff .aClass')
```

it works fine

Can someone please show me the correct syntax to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a + in your code.

Try this(changed the code to include the $j('#inputText') in the ready event..just in case..

```
$j(document).ready(function() {     
   var inputField= $j('#inputText').val();
    $j(".button").click(function (){    
        $j('#result').load('http://site.com?parameter='+inputField +' .aClass')
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks... now it submits the request without error but it is no longer recognizing the specific element I am trying to grab ".aClass" but is instead appending that to the ?parameter=stuff.aClass

Comment: You mean you want to grab the element with the className .aClass and append its value to the URL?

Comment: it's missing a space after the, it's fixed in my answer, but yeah, it's a simple fix.

Comment: Thx..Followed the original post hence the space was missing. Updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

```
$j(document).ready(function() {     
    $j(".button").click(function (){
        var inputField= $j('#inputText').val();    
        $j('#result').load('http://site.com?parameter='+inputField+' .aClass')
    });
});
```

Comment: Where I create the variable does not sem to be making any difference.  Firebug is saying I am missing a ) after arguments list ?

Comment: yeah i missed it, it was missing a + after inputField.

Comment: @zac, and you didn't think posting the error message in your question might've been helpful?

Comment: @david.. yea sorry didnt notice that when i originally asked